# How do I know when character is entered in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, character, uitextview

I am working on an Objective-C project. I want an event to be triggered after UITextView delegate, shouldChangeTextInRange returns TRUE. But I can't seem to find any. I want to update other variables while every character is added in UITextView.

If there is no even available, how can I customise shouldChangeTextInRange method if cursor is moved to the middle of text string and backspace is tapped or character is added?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: please upvote my question. I have already edited.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you return `TRUE` in

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

the `UITextView` `text` will be replaced with new one.

If you want to know the text contained in `UITextView` before returning `TRUE` in the `delegate` function, you can use the following method in `NSString` to obtain it. Make sure that you use the method in the `delegate` method of `UITextView`

```
NSString * strText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```